# How to avoid repetitive strain injuries when using LaTeX daily?

Tags: keyboard

LaTeX makes use of some characters that are not easy to type using a normal keyboard (like `\`, `{`, `}`, `[` and `]`). When typesetting math, you also have to constantly switch between the previous characters and digits, which can't be done in a fluid manner.

In my case, I have been typing the last few months on a laptop without a numeric pad which is the worst idea ever (I've already a tendonitis to the left little finger).

I know this is not really a question related to LaTeX, but I want to know how you deal with lots of LaTeX typing. Have you remapped some keys? Have you bought an extra keyboard?

Comment: Is this a joke?

Comment: Not at all! Even if I must say that having a tendonitis because of too much LaTeX typing is quite funny.